# arrays in sas with different dimensions

Tags: sas

Beginning with a table,

```
A B C D E 
1 . 1 . 1
. . 1 . .
. 1 . 1 .
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
A B C D E     X Y Z
1 . 1 . 1     1 1 1
. . 1 . .     1 
. 1 . 1 .     1 1
```

Here is my code:

```
data want; 
set have; 

array GG(5) A-E; 
array BB(3) X Y Z;

do i=1 to 5;
do j=1 to 3;     
if gg(i)=1 then BB(j)=1; 
end; 
end; 
run;
```

I understand that the result that I get is wrong, as the dimensions of both the arrays are not co-operating. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: may you show us the logic of when x,y,z would be assigned as 1?

Comment: @yukclam9 there are a max of 3 , 1s in a row and these are to be taken in to three new variables. 
The first 1 should go to X, second to Y and third to Z

Answer (score 2):

```
data want;
   set have;
   array v1 a--e;
   array v2 x y z;
   i=1;
   do over v1;
      if not missing(of v1) then do;
         v2(i)=v1;
         i+1;
      end;
   end;
   drop i;
run;
```

Comment: `do over` is deprecated, so you ought to do this with an iterator, but otherwise this is good.

Comment: @shenglin Chen
only the last variable which has one is being taken in X and Y Z are blank

Comment: @Joe is right., its better to have an iteration.
Here is the solutions

`code` data want;
 `code`   set have;
   `code` array v1 a--e;
   `code` array v2 x y z;
   `code` j=1;
`code`   do i=1 to 5;
`code`      if not missing(of v1(i)) then do;
`code`         v2(j)=v1;
`code`         j=j+1;
`code`      end; 
`code`   end;
`code`   drop i j;
`code` run; `code`

Answer (score 0):

My method is to copy the existing values to new variables X Y X temp1 temp2, then sort the values using `call sortn`, which will put the 1's and missing values together.  Because `call sortn` only sorts in ascending order, with missing values coming first, I've reversed the variables in the array statement (creating them first in the correct order with a `retain` statement.

The unwanted variables temp1 and temp2 can then be dropped.

```
data have;
input A B C D E;
datalines;
1 . 1 . 1
. . 1 . .
. 1 . 1 .
;
run;

data want;
set have;
retain X Y Z .; /* create new variables in required order */
array GG{5} A--E;
array BB{5} temp1 temp2 Z Y X; /* array in reverse order due to ascending sort later on */
do i = 1 to dim(GG);
    BB{i} = GG{i};
end;
call sortn(of BB{*}); /* sort array (missing values come first, hence the reverse array order) */
drop temp: i; /* drop unwanted variables */
run;
```

Alternatively, here's a simpler solution as your criteria is pretty basic.  As you're just dealing with 1's and missings, you can loop through the number of non-missing values in A-E and assign 1 to the new array.

```
data want;
set have;
array GG{5} A--E;
array BB{3} X Y Z;
do i = 1 to n(of GG{*});
    BB{i}=1;
end;
drop i; /* drop unwanted variable*/
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

why not something like this using a counter to identify which position is the actual non missing value?

```
data try;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input var1 var2 var3 var4 var5;
   datalines;                      
1,.,.,1,1,
.,1,.,.,.,
.,.,.,.,.,
.,1,.,1,.,
;
data want;
set try;
array vars[5] var1 var2 var3 var4 var5;
array newvars[5] nvar1 nvar2 nvar3 nvar4 nvar5;
do i=1 to 5;
if i=1 then count=0;
if vars[i] ne . then do;
count=count+1;
newvars[count]=vars[i];
end;
end;
drop i count var:;
run;
```